# Import and overwrite existing data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, import

I have data in a MySQL table with a unique key. I want to import more recent data that is stored in a CSV at the moment. I would like it to overwrite the old data if the key already exists, or create a new row if the key does not exist. Does anyone know how to this in MySQL?

Thank you for your help!

Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

```
INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES ('value') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE column='value'
```

Comment: thanks @ceejayoz. So is it then easy to incorporate that with the import of a CSV?

Answer (score 1):

use [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: thanks @bensiu. So is it then easy to incorporate that with the import of a CSV?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the answer to the originator's exact question here I can see by his last comment/question he was looking for something more.  It stimulated the following solution.

Nestling another shell environment (e.g. MYSQL) inside a script or batch file brings a lot of headaches switching syntaxes.  I tend to look for solutions that operate within one shell to cut down on those complications.  I have found this command string:

> mysqlimport --fields-terminated-by=, --ignore-lines=1 --local -uMYSQL_ACCT -pACCT_PWD YOUR_DB_NAME /PATH_TO/YOUR_TABLE_NAME.csv

I got this idea from Jausion's comment at [MySQL 5.0 RefMan :: 4.5.5 mysqlimport w/Jausions Comment](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html)  In a nutshell, you may import to a database table in a csv format by simply naming the csv file after the table and append the .csv extension.  You may append to the table and even overwrite rows.

Here is a real life csv file content of one of my operations.  I like to make human readable csv files that include the column headers in the first line, hence the --ignore-lines=1 option.

### id,TdlsImgVnum,SnapDate,TdlsImgDesc,ImageAvbl

### ,12.0.3.171-090915-1,09/09/2015,Enhanced CHI,Y

NOTICE the comma is the first char, making the first field value "NULL".

Here is the linux bash command that created the second line:

### echo null,"$LISTITEM","$IMG_DATE","$COMMENTS","$AVBL" | tee -a YOUR_TABLE_NAME.csv

What is important to know here is that the null field for the primary key id field allows mysql auto-increment to be applied and then just adds a new row to your table.  Sorry, can't recall if I read this somewhere or learned it the hard way:)

**So, Viola!, conversely and of MORE importance to this question is, you may OVERWRITE a whole row of data by supplying the primary key of the row in question.**

I am just in the throes of designing a new table to fulfill exactly these requirements with the overwrite operation but, as I alluded to, I already use the NULL append-a-row auto-increment option.

Comment: Completed the application and need to add what I have learned.  When overwriting a row (specifying the primary key row number), the mysqlimport command needs the --replace option!