# Import CSV into MySQL on duplicate key update

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I have a table looks like this.

```
create table test1 (
id1 varchar(10),
id2 varchar(10),
value1 varchar(10),
value2 varchar(10),
primary key (id1, id2)
);
```

which contains the data looks like this:

```
id1    id2    value1    value2
stan   marsh    1         2
eric   cartman  3         4
```

I  have a local CSV file which contains the updated data (contains new and old) looks like this:

```
"stan", "marsh", "5", "6"
"kyle", "broflovski", "7", "8"
```

How to import the csv file an meanwhile, update on duplicate key.

Few Links that might be helpful

1. [Import and overwrite existing data in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517779/import-and-overwrite-existing-data-in-mysql) (Same question but it was not answered properly)
2. [Mysql Insert on duplicate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: I believe this is the link you need: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html  Look at the `REPLACE` clause.

Comment: Possible duplicate, and if not it seems to answer the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271202/mysql-load-data-infile-with-on-duplicate-key-update

Comment: Hello friends, I have a table with 7 columns, the primary key does not work for me very much for this query, since it is based on columns and values, I want to insert or update a single column from a csv file; The problem is that Duplicate is not used correctly, and if possible for this scenario: if in a row three of the columns A, B, C match their values (already exists a record) do the update; If there is no match make an insert in the queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks a lot for the tiny flag advised by PM 77-1.

```
load data local infile '/Users/myuserID/Desktop/test1.csv' 
replace 
into table test.test1 
columns terminated by ',' 
enclosed by '"' 
lines terminated by '\n';
```

Comment: I see this is an old answer, but be careful with `REPLACE`, it will perform a `DELETE` then `INSERT`. If you have foreign keys, you may loose the child data. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271202/mysql-load-data-infile-with-on-duplicate-key-update

Comment: Hello friends, I have a table with 7 columns, the primary key does not work for me very much for this query, since it is based on columns and values, I want to insert or update a single column from a csv file; The problem is that Duplicate is not used correctly, and if possible for this scenario: if in a row three of the columns A, B, C match their values (already exists a record) do the update; If there is no match make an insert in the queue.